# Jquery form validation based on typeof required fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm doing form validation using jQuery I have used `id's` to every input field. Now I want to add jquery `typeof()` method if the field is text, textarea should be validated in one loop like this phone number and email and so on. I want to write it in an if/else condition. This form is working fine except radio and checkbox are not being validated(should throw an error when submitted). but now I want to change my code completely as I mentioned above. Feel free to tell if there are any mistakes. and I don't want to use any external plugins.

Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve?

Any help will be appreciated

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.success_msg').hide();

  /* name*/
  $('#contact_name').on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var regex = /^([^0-9]*)$/;
    var is_name = regex.test(input.val());
    if (is_name) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");

    }
  });

  /* E-mail */
  $('#contact_email').on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var regex = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
    var is_email = regex.test(input.val());
    if (is_email) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });

  /* Phone */
  $('#contact_phone').on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var regex = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
    var is_phone = regex.test(input.val());
    if (is_phone) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });

  /* message*/
  $('#contact_message, #contact_enquiry').keyup(function(event) {
    var input = $(this);
    var message = $(this).val();
    if (message) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });

  /* Radio button */


  $('#contact_male, #contact_female').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else if ($(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
      $(this).removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });

  /* Checkbox */


  // $('#contact_check').click(function(){
  //     if($(this).is(":checked")){
  //   $(this).removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  //     }
  //     else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
  //   $(this).removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  //     }
  // });


  /* Submit */
  $("#submit_form").click(function(event) {

    var form_data = $("#contact").serializeArray();

    var error_free = true;
    for (var input in form_data) {
      var element = $("#contact_" + form_data[input]['name']);
      var valid = element.hasClass("valid");
      var error_element = $("span", element.parent());

      if (!valid) {
        error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show");
        error_free = false;
      } else {
        error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");
      }
    }

    if (!error_free) {
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $('.success_msg').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
      $('input , textarea , select').val('').removeClass('valid');
      event.preventDefault();
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.success_msg {
  width: 350px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(213, 255, 187, 0.7);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
}

.iva-nav {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all 0.74s ease;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.iva-nav span {
  transform: translateZ(8px);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

.iva-nav:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.4);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 50;
}

.iva-nav:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.4);
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 25;
}

.iva-nav:hover:before {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.6);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.1);
}

.iva-nav:hover:after {
  transform: rotate(133deg);
  background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.6);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.1);
}

.fancy-heading-s1 {
  max-width: 1400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 25px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.fancy-heading-s2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.fancy-title {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.cfar-s1 .cfar-heading {
  text-align: center;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.cfar {
  max-width: 1140px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cfar-s1 {
  padding: 40px 100px;
  background-color: #313439;
}

.cfar-s1 .fancy-title span {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cfar-s1 .fancy-title span:after {
  content: " . ";
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-15%);
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.cfar-s1 .fancy-title span:last-child:after {
  content: "";
  margin-right: 0;
}

.cfar-s1 .fancy-heading-s2 h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cfar-s1 .fancy-heading-s2 h2 span {
  color: #da4e5b;
}

.cfar-s1 form {
  padding: 30px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.cfar .detail {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
  flex-basis: 48%;
}

.cfar .detail input,
.detail textarea,
.detail select {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.cfar option {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.cfar .detail textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: none;
}

.cfar .detail label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.43s ease-in-out;
}

.cfar .detail .inputBar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.43s ease-in-out;
}

.cfar .detail input:focus:after,
.detail textarea:foucs:after,
.detail select:focus:after,
.cfar .detail .inputBar:focus:before,
.cfar .detail .inputBar:focus:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 2px;
}

.cfar .detail .inputBar:after {
  right: 50%;
}

.cfar .detail .inputBar:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.cfar .detail input:focus~label,
.cfar .detail input:valid~label,
.cfar .detail textarea:focus~label,
.cfar .detail textarea:valid~label {
  top: -20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.cfar .detail input:focus~.inputBar:before,
.cfar .detail input:focus~.inputBar:after,
.cfar .detail textarea:focus~.inputBar:before,
.cfar .detail textarea:focus~.inputBar:after .cfar .detail select:focus~.inputBar:before,
.cfar .detail select:focus~.inputBar:after {
  width: 50%;
}

.cfar .detail .answer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 114px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  left: 133px;
  position: inherit;
}


/* custom css*/

span.error {
  /*display: none;*/
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px !important;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.error_show {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  color: red;
}

input:focus {
  outline-width: 0;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: none;
}


/*-------------------------------------------------------------
  contact form style 1
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.cfar-s1 .detail input,
.cfar-s1 .detail textarea,
.cfar-s1 .detail select {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}

.cfar-s1 .detail .inputBar {
  position: relative;
}

.cfar-s1 .detail .inputBar:before {
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -1px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.cfar-s1 .detail input:focus~.inputBar:before,
.cfar-s1 .detail textarea:focus~.inputBar:before {
  width: 100%;
}

.cfar-s1 .detail label {
  top: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #777777;
}

.message {
  flex-basis: 100% !important;
}

.btn-container {
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.btn-container .btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: #da4e5b;
  padding: 20px 75px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contactform1">
  <div id="note"></div>
  <form id="contact" method="post" action="">
    <div id="note"></div>
    <div class="detail">
      <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="name" autocomplete="off" required />
      <span class="inputBar"></span>
      <!--inputBar-->
      <label for="contact_name">Name</label>
      <span class="error">This field is required</span>
    </div>
    <!--detail-->
    <div class="detail">
      <input type="text" id="contact_email" name="email" autocomplete="off" required />
      <span class="inputBar"></span>
      <!--inputBar-->

      <label for="contact_email">Email</label>
      <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>
    </div>
    <!--detail-->
    <div class="detail">
      <input type="number" id="contact_phone" autocomplete="off" name="phone" required />
      <span class="inputBar"></span>
      <!--inputBar-->
      <label for="contact_phone">Phone Number</label>
      <span class="error">A valid Phone number is required</span>
    </div>
    <!--detail-->
    <div class="detail">
      <input type="text" id="contact_enquiry" autocomplete="off" name="enquiry" required />
      <span class="inputBar"></span>
      <!--inputBar-->
      <label for="contact_enquiry">I want to know about...</label>
      <span class="error">This field is required</span>
    </div>
    <!--detail-->
    <div class="detail message">
      <textarea type="text" id="contact_message" autocomplete="off" name="message" required></textarea>
      <span class="inputBar"></span>
      <!--inputBar-->
      <label for="contact_message">Type your Message here</label>
      <span class="error">This field is required</span>
    </div>
    <!--detail-->

    <div class="detail">
      <span class="inputBar"></span>
      <!--inputBar-->
      <input type="radio" id="contact_male" name="male" required />Male
      <input type="radio" id="contact_female" name="female" required />Female
      <span class="error">This field is required</span>
    </div>
    <!--detail-->


    <div class="detail">
      <span class="inputBar"></span>
      <!--inputBar-->
      <input type="checkbox" id="contact_html" name="html" required />HTMl
      <input type="checkbox" id="contact_css" name="css" required />CSS
      <span class="error">This field is required</span>
    </div>
    <!--detail-->


    <div class="btn-container" id="submit_form">
      <a href="#">Submit</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](http://formvalidation.io/examples/), your queries will be answered.